# Downloads stops - "TCP Window Full"

Tags: windows-7, java, tcp

During the last weeks I encounter a lot of download problems of all programs that are based on Java (Eclipse, Maven, Android SDK manager, ...). The download starts and runs fine until suddenly it stops completely and never continues.
When I download the same problematic files with other programs e.g. using wget the download is running without any problems.

A further analysis with Wireshark shows that when the download stops a "*TCP window full*" message is sent and afterwards only "*TCP ZeroWindow*" messages  are getting sent.

System: Windows 7 32bit with Oracle JDK 1.7.0_03. Downgrading to 1.6.0_31 does not help...

Native Windows applications doesn't seem to be affected.

Anybody an idea how to proceed?

**Edit:**

I tried to fix my problem by changing the TCP reception window enlarging algorithm (command `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`). But it doesn't matter which mode I use - disabled, restricted, normal, ... the problem still persists.

**Edit 2:**

Even after a complete reinstallation this problem persists. Therefore I started to disable/deinstalling programs. At the moment the most promising culprit is AVG Free 2012 or to be precise the "Link Scanner" component.

Comment: Try updating Java to the latest version. I don't know if your issue has anything with this: [http://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/03/new-java-attack-rolled-into-exploit-packs/](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/03/new-java-attack-rolled-into-exploit-packs/)

Comment: @Radoo: Please take a closer look onto the Java versions I noted - these are the latest versions!

Comment: Sorry, I looked I don't know where and saw some 1.7.1, but I can't find it now. I have no other clue, if only it happens in Java... Might be some driver used just by Java.

Comment: @Radoo: Java doesn't install any drivers. The only service it installs is just for pre-loading the JVM at boot-time.

Comment: Could it be that some security/firewall/antivirus software is getting triggered?

Comment: I would say that there is a bug in the applications that has caused them to hang or otherwise stop reading from the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing ipv4:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

ref: 
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2309363